# Query to get last conversations for user inbox

Tags: postgresql

I need a specific SQL query to select last 10 conversations for user inbox. 
Inbox shows only conversations(threads) with every user - it selects the last message from the conversation and shows it in inbox.

Edited.

Expecting result: to extract `latest message` from each of `10 latest conversations`. Facebook shows latest conversations in the same way

And one more question. How to make a `pagination` to show next 10 latest messages from previous latest conversations in the next page?

Private messages in the database looks like:

```
| id | user_id | recipient_id | text
| 1  | 2       | 3            | Hi John!
| 2  | 3       | 2            | Hi Tom! 
| 3  | 2       | 3            | How are you? 
| 4  | 3       | 2            | Thanks, good! You?
```

Comment: can you provide with a output of results you are expecting, in the above case, I assume only 1 record for user_id 2, having the latest messge for him as 'Thanks, good! You?'

Comment: Added! Thanks for helping ;) Yes you are right, I need only the last message of this conversation, +9 more laste messages from other latest conversations...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my understanding, you need to get the latest message of the conversation on per-user basis (of the last 10 latest conversations)

**Update:** I have modified the query to get the `latest_conversation_message_id` for every user conversation

The below query gets the details for `user_id = 2`, you can modify, `users.id = 2` to get it for any other user

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/4021d/12)**, hope this solves your purpose

```
SELECT
    user_id, 
    users.name, 
    users2.name as sent_from_or_sent_to,
    subquery.text as latest_message_of_conversation
FROM
    users
    JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        text,
        row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY user_id + recipient_id ORDER BY id DESC) AS row_num,
        user_id,
        recipient_id,
        id
    FROM
        private_messages
    GROUP BY
        id,
        recipient_id,
        user_id,
        text
    ) AS subquery ON ( ( subquery.user_id = users.id OR subquery.recipient_id = users.id)  AND row_num = 1 )
    JOIN users as users2 ON ( users2.id = CASE WHEN users.id = subquery.user_id THEN subquery.recipient_id ELSE subquery.user_id END )
WHERE
    users.id = 2
ORDER BY
    subquery.id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

**Info:** The query gets the latest message of every conversation with any other user, If `user_id 2`, sends a message to `user_id 3`, that too is displayed, as it indicates the start of a conversation. The latest message of every conversation with any other user is displayed

Comment: Thanks! It is a little bit too advanced for me :) Maybe there is a way to transform it to receive only private_messages ids not by including users table? (I need to extract latest message id from each 10 latest conversations) Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks Akash! Your answer provides exactly results I have been expecting, plus you have made a query to get user params. Could you paste your code from the fiddle to your answer? It will be useful for others!

Comment: Thanks! Just one more thing to reach the perfection of this query :) In inbox it is better to show the recipient in all conversations. Now if I have sent the last message, query gives my own params. Is it posible to get opponent of the conversation params every time, even if the last message is mine?

Comment: @Lucas Yes, I have updated the answer (and the fiddle too :) ), I have changed the last join, to handle it as, if the current_user_id == the_latest_message_user_id, then use the recipient_id instead, else use the the_latest_message_user_id

Answer (score 2):

To solve groupwise-max in pg you can use `DISTINCT ON`. Like this:

```
SELECT
DISTINCT ON(pm.user_id)
    pm.user_id, 
    pm.text
FROM
    private_messages AS pm
WHERE pm.recipient_id= <my user id>
ORDER BY pm.user_id, pm.id DESC;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/4021d/19

To get the latest X however we will have to use it in a subselect:

```
SELECT
q.user_id,
q.id,
q.text
FROM
(
SELECT
DISTINCT ON(pm.user_id)
    pm.user_id,
pm.id,
    pm.text
FROM
    private_messages AS pm
WHERE pm.recipient_id=2
ORDER BY pm.user_id, pm.id DESC
  ) AS q
ORDER BY q.id DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/4021d/28

To get both sent and recieved threads:

```
SELECT
q.user_id,
q.recipient_id,
q.id,
    q.text
FROM
(
SELECT
DISTINCT ON(pm.user_id,pm.recipient_id)
    pm.user_id,
    pm.recipient_id,
pm.id,
    pm.text
FROM
    private_messages AS pm
WHERE pm.recipient_id=2 OR pm.user_id=2
ORDER BY pm.user_id,pm.recipient_id, pm.id DESC
  ) AS q
ORDER BY q.id DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/4021d/42

Comment: this would not include the conversation started by the sender

Comment: @Akash you're right, I updated with query that would do that.

Comment: Thanks for the simple and clean query. It gives not exactly what I wanted, but still does it's job - selects two last messages of each conversation. Sometimes it can be usefull to show for users which messages they have already replied..

Comment: @Lucas How about this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/38704/1 ? This one should return the last msg of the thread no matter if it was sent or recieved by the user. A solution using `DISTINCT ON` gotta be possible but I'm a bit confused about what the query should do.

Comment: @JakubKania thanks, now it works! Is it possible to receive the Opponent params in the same query? It would be great to get user title in the same query to whom I'm talking with...

Comment: @Lucas Everything is possible in pg :) You can use case in the joins `JOIN users AS uON (CASE WHEN q.recipient_id<>2 THEN q.recipient_id ELSE q.user_id END)`. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/38704/5

Answer (score 0):

Paste it after your WHERE clause

```
ORDER BY "ColumnName" [ASC, DESC]
```

[UNION Description at W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) it combines the result of this 2 statements.

```
SELECT "ColumnName" FROM "TableName"
UNION
SELECT "ColumnName" FROM "TableName"
```

Comment: thanks! But I need to limit messages somehow. I need to take only the last message with every user. Conversation with each user can has 100 and more messages instead..

Comment: as u wrote in your statement u use LIMIT 10 with the ORDER columnName u can turn the result ASC or DESC.

Answer (score 0):

For large data sets I think you might like to try running the two statements and then consolidating the results, as an index scan on (user_id and id) or (recipient_id and id) ought to be very efficient at getting the 10 most recent conversations of each type.

```
with sent_messages as (
  SELECT   *
  FROM     private_messages
  WHERE    user_id = my_user_id
  ORDER BY id desc
  LIMIT    10),
received_messages as (  SELECT   *
  FROM     private_messages
  WHERE    recipient_id = my_user_id
  ORDER BY id desc
  LIMIT    10),
all_messages as (
  select *
  from   sent_messages
  union all
  select *
  from   received_messages)
select   *
from     all_messages
order by id desc
limit    10
```

Edit: Actually another query worth trying might be:

```
select *
from   private_messages
where  id in (
         select id
         from   (
           SELECT   id
           FROM     private_messages
           WHERE    user_id = my_user_id
           ORDER BY id desc
           LIMIT    10
           union all
           SELECT   id
           FROM     private_messages
           WHERE    recipient_id = my_user_id
           ORDER BY id desc
           LIMIT    10) all_ids
          order by id desc
          limit 10) last_ten_ids
order by id desc
```

This might be better in 9.2+, where the indexes alone could be used to get the id's, or in cases where the most recent number to retrieve is very large. Still a bit unclear on that though. If in doubt I'd go for the former version.

Comment: looks really efficient. But I have got some errors with both of queries: "syntax error at or near "union". What can be wrong here? 
And How can I transform the query to get only 10 latest conversations from both queries, not from each other? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Lucas postgres didn't seem to like the order by or the limit in the queries being union'ed, so I broke them out to common table expressions. Seems to be good: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/91dac/6

Comment: something went wrong - it selects two or more mesages from each conversation. I have already got the query I needed. Thanks for helping!!